# show integrals are equivalent

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, substitution

> How does one show that these integrals are equal?

$$ \int_0^1 e^{A(x)}~dx $$

$$ \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{B(x)}~dx $$

$A(x)=\frac{1}{\log(x)}$

$B(x)=-\sqrt{4+x^2}$

I tried to represent the first integral in a different way and go from there:

$$I:=\int_0^1\exp\frac{1}{\log x}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{y^2}\exp -(y+y^{-1})dy=\frac12\int_0^\infty(1+1/y^2)\exp -(y+y^{-1})dy$$

where I used the substitution $y=-1/\log(x)$ and then averaged with $1/y.$

Then this is equivalent to the well known Bessel representation by making the substitution $y=e^{-t}$:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp[-2\cosh t]\cosh tdt$$

From here I am stuck...I don't see how to proceed to obtain: $$ \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{B(x)}~dx $$

Comment: Have you tried to use the substitution $\frac{1}{\ln(x)}=-\sqrt{4+u^2}$?

Comment: @Lorago that substitution doesn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've managed to show that
$$
\int_0^1 e^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}\, \mathrm{d}x = \frac12\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\left(\frac{1}{y} +y \right)}\, \left( \frac{1}{y^2} +1\right)\mathrm{d}y
$$
From here take the substitution $ u = \frac{1}{y} -y\implies \, -\mathrm{d}u= \left( \frac{1}{y^2} +1\right)\mathrm{d}y$ and noticing that $$
\left(\frac{1}{y}+y \right)^2 = \frac{1}{y^2} \color{blue}{+ 2} + y^2 = \frac{1}{y^2} \color{blue}{- 2} + y^2 \color{blue}{+4} =\left(\frac{1}{y}-y \right)^2 +4
$$
we conclude
$$
\int_0^1 e^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}\, \mathrm{d}x = \frac12\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\left(\frac{1}{y} +y \right)}\, \left( \frac{1}{y^2} +1\right)\mathrm{d}y \overset{u = 1/y -y}{=} \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\sqrt{u^2 +4}}\, \mathrm{d}u
$$
as desired.